# simple UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, promise, try-catch

When I try to run this, i get "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning". But last "catch" received control anyway with correct "err" object.
I have got two warnings:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
>
> PromiseRejectionHandledWarning

If I comment "return delay(5000);" all works fine.
Why does Node.JS handle "promiseErr" before I do that?

```
const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

let promiseErr = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error("__error__"));
});

let promiseOk = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
    });

promiseOk
    .then( () => {
        return delay(5000);
    })
    .then( () => {
        return promiseErr;
    })
    .then( () => {
        console.log("OK");
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.log(`ERR ${err}`);
    });
```

[program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAUIP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rejected promise asynchronously (after 5000ms). Node.js detects unhandled promises by looking at promises that were not handled synchronously or within a microtick (inside a `then`).

Since Node.js cannot know "for sure" when a promise rejection is unhandled at the moment it errors on the safe side and gives you the warning. It is generally better to add catch handlers to promise errors synchronously as much as possible.

You can suppress the warning by adding a `.catch(() => {})` to `promiseErr` when you create it which will handle the exception:

```
var promiseErr = ...
promiseErr.catch(() => {}); // add a catch handler without changing the original
```

In general - the solution is to not write code in such an error prone way. If `promiseOk` or `delay` rejects (which Node has no way of knowing) - then the exception in `promiseErr` itself is indeed unhandeld - so this is not really a safe way to write code.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I just thought "promiseErr" would keep it's state until I decide to handle it.

Comment: Sure, if you feel like this answer answered your question then please consider accepting it at some point